# Broken Shell with Conditional Step Plugin - Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins

I use Conditional Steps Plugin in Jenkins to send mail when a file exists. 
I've tried with the following:

[image]

And with this command: `mpack -s "Test Mail" /file.csv myemail@something.com`

But I get the following Console Output from Jenkins:

```
[File exists] check if file exists [file.csv]
Run condition [File exists] preventing perform for step [Execute shell]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

And I don't get any email...
Even writing: echo "HELLO", doesn't happen anything.
The problem is with the condition "File exists", because I've tried to do with "Always" condition, and it worked.

What could be happening with this condition "File exists"?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Where have you kept your `.csv` file?

Comment: In the folder called "/test-output /" inside my workspace.

Comment: I've tried to put:

mpack -s "Test Mail from Jenkins" **/file.csv myemail@something.com. 

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried it by providing the absolute path?

Comment: Yep, absolute path and relative path, and nothing happens...

Comment: But I've just noticed that if I put only "echo "HELLO"" in the Shell Command, neither it happens nothing... why doesn't it run?? thanks!

Comment: Does your Jenkins server have outbound email configured?

Comment: @tripleee yes, my Jenkins send mail through "Mail Notification Action", but when I want to send it through "Conditional Step - Command Shell", my Jenkins doesn't recognize any command (even "echo").

Comment: Sounds like your shell is broken then. Maybe [edit] your question and its title to reflect that your problem appears to be much different than what you thought when you initially posted. (Or delete this question and post a new one; but realize that repeatedly deleting your questions is regarded as abuse.)

Comment: Thanks @tripleee I did it. What is the cause that my shell is broken??

Comment: Without further diagnostics, no idea. Maybe see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-3490 for some troubleshooting steps to try.

Comment: Yeah... I saw it, but that issue wasn't resolved...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided your `.csv` file name in the file field and have chosen your base directory as `Workspace`. As `Files Match` condition only takes a file name and checks for it directly in the workspace and not inside the sub-folders of your workspace it is not able to find it and hence the process gets terminated there.

I suggest you to use `Files match` instead of `File exists`.

`File exists` only looks for a single file that is present in your job's workspace directly and you cannot provide any absolute path or Ant GLOB format path to your file.

However, if you use `Files match` you can look for multiple files and provide the path to your files in your workspace using Ant GLOB format.

In your case you have to choose `Files Match` as the `Run?` condition and provide the path to your file i.e. `**/your_file.csv`

[image]

Comment: Perfect ANIL, thanks so much. It works!!!!                                            
 Files match condition: Matched [1] files
Run condition [Files match] enabling perform for step [Execute shell]
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1433298668224524769.sh
+ echo HELLO
HELLO
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Now I want to send a mail when the files match, but I've tried with:

Comment: mailx -s 'Test Mail from Jenkins' -a **/my_file.csv my@email.com   but it returns failure "mailx: not found"

Comment: sendmail -f sender@some.where -t receiver@some.place -m -a file1.csv   and returns "sendmail: not found"

Comment: mpack -s "Subject here" file.csv user@example.com  and returns "mpack: not found"

Comment: @UserMB `mailx`, `sendmail` and `mpack` these are separate programs. First you have to install them in your system to use them.

Comment: I fixed it installing postfix. THanks so much ANIL!

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped then please accept it :)